# Insert into a table where column values are passed as comma delimeted values

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following script where i want to insert into a table where column name can be passed as comma delimited values. Please suggest different approaches to achieve the following output.

```
Declare @col_by_source varchar(250) = 's1,s2,s3',
    @column_by_target varchar(250) = 'c1,c2,c3',
    @SQLString nvarchar(max)


Set @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourceTable] (
                  ['+@col_by_source+'] )'

set @SQLString = @SQLString+' '+'SELECT '

Select @SQLString = @SQLString + QUOTENAME(split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) + ' AS '+@col_by_source+','
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@column_by_target, ',', '</M><M>')+ '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
CROSS apply data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a); 

Set @SQLString = LEFT(@SQLString, LEN(@SQLString) - 1) + ')' 

Set @SQLString = @SQLString + 'FROM tableA_source'
print @SQLString
```

OUTPUT:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourceTable] (
              [s1,s2,s3] ) SELECT [c1] AS s1,s2,s3,[c2] AS s1,s2,s3,[c3] AS s1,s2,s3 FROM tableA_source
```

Expected Output:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourceTable] (
          [s1,s2,s3] ) SELECT [c1] AS s1, [c2] AS s2,[c3] AS s3 
FROM tableA_source
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it as simple. You won't need an alias while doing insert....select.

try like this,

```
DECLARE @col_by_source VARCHAR(250) = 's1,s2,s3'
    ,@column_by_target VARCHAR(250) = 'c1,c2,c3'
    ,@SQLString NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourceTable] (
                  ' + @col_by_source + ' )'
SET @SQLString = @SQLString + ' ' + 'SELECT '

SELECT @SQLString = @SQLString + QUOTENAME(split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) + ' ,'
FROM (
    SELECT Cast('<M>' + Replace(@column_by_target, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
    ) AS A
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/M') AS Split(a);

SET @SQLString = LEFT(@SQLString, LEN(@SQLString) - 1) + ''
SET @SQLString = @SQLString + 'FROM tableA_source'

PRINT @SQLString
```

Comment: INSERT INTO [sourceTable](
s1,s2,s3
)
SELECT
 '~N' AS c1,
 '~N' AS c2,
 '~N' AS c3  in such cases i need to implement aliases. Could you suggest anything? @StackUser